# File Transform task does not work in Release pipeline for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am trying to deploy a Xamarin.Forms application using Azure DevOps. Before actual deployment, I need to use File Transform task to change values in a json file. I provide a path to .apk (for Android) or to .ipa (for iOS) in the "Package or folder" field of the task. I get the following error:

> Invalidwebapppackageorfolderpathprovided D:\a\r1\a_Android App-CI\drop\Release\com.somename.mobile.apk

Does it mean that I cannot use File Transform with .apk and .ipa, and the only type allowed is .zip?

P.S. I have this task in the release pipeline rather than in build pipeline for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that I cannot use File Transform with .apk and .ipa, and the only type allowed is .zip?

Yes, you are right. This task does not support the `.apk` and `.ipa` file.

You could check the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/FileTransformV2/filetransform.ts) for this task on the github, you could find following code snippet:

```
import path = require('path');
import { Package } from 'azure-pipelines-tasks-webdeployment-common/packageUtility';
```

For the `{ Package }`, we check the code from `azure-pipelines-tasks-webdeployment-common/packageUtility.ts` file:

[packageUtility.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/Common/webdeployment-common-v2/packageUtility.ts)

```
export enum PackageType {
    war,
    zip,
    jar,
    folder
}
```

So, the type allowed are `war` `zip` `jar` `folder` but not `.apk` and `.ipa`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other way to do it? Another task?